# Matrices as generators of free group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, free-groups

In the introduction section of the paper [Triples of $2\times 2$ matrices which generate free groups](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-059-01/S0002-9939-1976-0412272-4/S0002-9939-1976-0412272-4.pdf) the authors mentioning some thing...

In my words:

> The matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ are generating the *free group* of two generators.

How to prove the above statement?

Comment: Take a look at the references in the paper you are reading.

Comment: Well, one of the references is in German, the other is in Russian. So the request is perhaps not unreasonable.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: And another one (Lyndon and Ullman) is in English.

Answer (score 5):

This is nothing more than an application of the [Ping-Pong Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma#Special_linear_group_example).

Comment: John Meier gives a wonderful explanation of this in his book *Groups, graphs and trees*.

Answer (score 4):

It can be proven using the Ping Pong lemma. You can see the proof in Pierre de la Harpe's book *Topics in geometric group theory*.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a particular case of Theorem 14.2.1 in Kargapolov and Merzljakov, "Fundamentals of the Theory of Groups", but you can easily adapt their proof to your case.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is in the [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-2/Pairs-of-real-2-by-2-matrices-that-generate-free/10.1307/mmj/1028999969.full) of Lyndon and Ullman.

Comment: Now comes the hardest part...

Comment: Yes, you have to learn how to play ping-pong without a partner. Some people find it difficult, but you should try, you will find it very useful later on, if you want to do group theory.